# How do I declare a string as a user input, then check to see if it's "yes" or "no"? (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, variable-assignment, equals, java.util.scanner

I cannot get my program to take a user input as a string and then see if it equals "yes" or "no" and if it equals neither, then to display "incorrect entry." It always displays "incorrect entry" regardless if I type "yes" or "no." I have tried a few different types of if and do/while's but I just can't seem to get it:

Class file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhysicsProblem
{
private double vI; // initial velocity  
private double vF; // final velocity    
private double t;  // time 
private double deltaX;  // change in the x value

//Make sure to add acceleration
public PhysicsProblem (double vI, double vF, double t, double deltaX) 
{
    this.vI = vI;
    this.vF = vF;
    this.t = t;
    this.deltaX = deltaX;   
}

public void setVi(String strVi)
{
    while (!(strVi.equals("no") || strVi.equals("yes")));
    {
        System.out.println("incorrect entry");  
    }
    if (strVi.equals("yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the initial velocity: ");
        vI = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
    }
    if (strVi.equals("no"))
    {
        System.out.println("The program is assuming you want to solve" +
                            "for intial velocity");
    }
}
```

Program:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class PhysicsProblemSolver
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    double vI = 0;
    double vF = 0;
    double t = 0;
    double deltaX = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    PhysicsProblem problem1 = new PhysicsProblem (vI, vF, t, deltaX);

    // Checks to see if initial velocity is given
    System.out.println("Do you know the initial velocity? (Type 'yes' or 'no')");
    String strVi = scan.next(); 
    problem1.setVi(strVi);
```

I know it looks like an incomplete program, and it is, but I just needed help with this one section, so I tried not to include the unnecessary parts. Sorry if it's confusing!

Comment: `while (!(strVi.equals("no") || strVi.equals("yes")));` is a deadlock!

Comment: what does "deadlock" mean? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!(strVi.equals("no") || strVi.equals("yes")));
```

will always evaluate to true if the input is neither 'yes' nor 'no' so it will go into infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the testing in main itself i you can,

```
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       String input;
        do{
            System.out.println("enter valid input");
        input=sc.next();            
       }while(!(input.equals("yes") || input.equals("no")));
```

Then simply pass input to function.

remove unnecessary checks there. as others mentioned its infinite loop(deadlock).

```
while (!(strVi.equals("no") || strVi.equals("yes")));
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
public void setVi(String strVi){
    if(strVi.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
        //What if yes
    }else if(strVi.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
        //What if no
    }else{
        //What if not yes nor no
    }
}
```